# Scrutor doesn't scan files from different sub projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, scrutor

I have the following structure for my project:

```
firstProj
|
+--- src
|    |
|    +--- Repositories
|         |
|         +--- MyFirstRepository.cs
|         +--- IMyFirstRepository.cs
|
secondProj
|
+--- src
     |
     +--- Repositories
          |
          +--- MySecondRepository.cs   
          +--- IMySecondRepository.cs
```

The `firstProject` contains a `Startup.cs` file, that has the following:

```cs
 services.Scan(scan => scan
     .FromEntryAssembly()
     .AddClasses(classes => classes
        .InNamespaces("my.namespaces"))
   .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Replace(ReplacementBehavior.ImplementationType))
   .AsImplementedInterfaces()
   .WithScopedLifetime());
```

The first repository is recognized and added to the pool, however, the second one doesn't. Both repositories are under `my.namespace` namespace, and if I manually add the first file:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IMyFirstRepository, MyFirstRepository>()
```

it works. Any ideas on how to make Scrutor scan all files?

Comment: .FromEntryAssembly() is the key here. You're only scanning a single assembly from which the program is starting therefore the 2nd repository which lives in the different assembly is not even remotely considered as a candidate.

You've to change it to either .FromAssemblyOf to selector.FromAssembliesOf and reference at least a single type from each assembly or use a method which scans assemblies with dependencies.

Comment: @user2184057 `FromAssemblies` didn't work neither.

Comment: The question is does the firstProj hold a reference to secondProj?

When you are using FromAssemblies have you correctly passed both assemblies as parameters? 

FromAssembliesOf(typeof(IMyFirstRepository), typeof(IMySecondRepository) should work.

It's not about repositories as much as it is about providing any type from each assembly so override can figure out an assembly to scan.

Comment: @user2184057 Yes, the first project uses `<ProjectReference Include="..\secondProj/secondProj.csproj" />`

Comment: @user2184057 Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: FromAssembliesOf(typeof(IMyFirstRepository), typeof(IMySecondRepository)) does it also no work?

Comment: @user2184057 That would work, but I have 50+ repositories. I don't want to add manually. I have a base entity class, `IBaseEntity<T>` but I can't pass it as the type varies.

Comment: You are missing the point of FromAssembliesOf(typeof(IMyFirstRepository), typeof(IMySecondRepository)) does it also no work? – You don't have to write down every repository here because you're not really providing a class in this overload rather an assembly which is being resolved based on a type therefore using this should force Scrutor to scan both assemblies for all repositories as long as they are placed within 
".InNamespaces("my.namespaces"))".

Also if you have some GenericInterface implemented in repository you can use something like this:

Comment: selector.FromAssembliesOf(typeof(FirstRepo), typeof(SecondRepo))
                    .AddClasses(filter =>
                    {
                        filter.AssignableToAny(typeof(IBaseRepository<,>), typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), typeof(ICommandHandler<,>));
                    })
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .WithScopedLifetime();
            });

Comment: @user2184057 That's very helpful. I didn't try it yet, but it seems very reasonable. You may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   builder.Services.Scan(scan =>
            scan.FromAssemblies()
                .AddClasses(classes => classes.InNamespaces("Repositories"))
                .AsSelf()
                .WithScopedLifetime());
```